# Divide frequency of live audiostream from an ultrasound microphone

Tags: pulseaudio, sox

I want to record ultrasound with a microphone, divide the frequency and listen to the transposed sound. I start with a normal microphone for tests.

I tried sox with rec and play so far. It works, but the latency is 2 seconds.

```
rec -r 48000  -c 1 -t wav - pitch -1000  | play -t wav -
```

How can I improve this line and reduce the latency?

My audio setup is

```
 # API: ALSA v: k6.1.27-gentoo status: kernel-api
 # Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: active
```

Comment: sox is really not intended for live processing; also, good pitch shifting necessarily needs quite some "signal history", thus latency, and good approximation with low latency are usually expensive. Hence: Stupid question from my side! When working with ultrasonic signals, do you really want to *pitch shift*, or do you want to *frequency translate*? The latter would be much easier, and what people usually want to do with ultrasonic pressure waves to observe them.

Comment: Note that part of your problem actually probably goes away once you actually deal with ultrasonic data, which necessarily is sampled at a higher rate than your audio sound card does. That *can*, if chosen appropriately, reduce a problem of shifting pitch to a problem of undersampling.

Comment: But very seriously: This is 100% a signal processing problem, only slightly an "implementation in sox" problem, and an "implementation in sox" problem is only by happenstance slightly a Unix&Linux problem. I'd recommend you ask the moderators to migrate this question to https://dsp.stackexchange.com !

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you. I updated my question. I thought I want to pitch. As I do not want to code a super complicate signal processor, but simply divide the frequency on the commandline, I guess the question fits slightly better to `unix.sx`

Comment: But the "divide the frequency" is "super complicated signal processing", and that's why you get seconds of latency (it needs signal history, for the resampling and for the time-stretching filters, so you cannot produce the pitch-shifted version of the signal without knowing a bit of "future" signal, mathematically. So that makes the latency inherent to the principle, not to `sox`) :-) that's why I said that. So, I mean, are you *sure* you want pitch-shifting and not frequency translation?

Comment: (*pitch shifting* is, as you correctly stated, dividing all signal components' frequencies by the same factor. *frequency translation* is when you subtract the same frequency from all signal components' frequencies. The former needs a time-stretching and a resampling algorithm, the latter just a multiplication with tone.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the parametrization you chose, it's mathematically impossible to give you output before there's significantly much input flown by.

Since pitch shifting (== frequency division) requires resampling filters, and time-stretching filters, it's intuitive to argue that these have *group delay*, and hence, being causal, you incur a significant delay between input signal and output signal. That's not `sox`'s fault – just how the math works out.

Solutions include:

- use a less drastic shift
- use a significantly higher input sampling rate
- don't go for pitch shift (== frequency division) but something else, like frequency translation

Linux/Unix/Tool knowledge can't help you here.

The problem really is that you're trying to do a large pitch shift at your output sampling rate; since your ultrasonic recorder must, for Nyquist reasons, already work at a much higher sampling rate, maybe this problem doesn't occur in this form in your actual application.